# Can you determine ball swing direction?

Tags: wii-sports

Is there a way to dictate which way the ball will swing if you overhit (making the swing meter go red) the ball in Wii Golf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this many times before to hook around certain objects while playing.  It is tricky but do-able.  To control the over powered hook, the meter will sway the direction of where your hand leaves off.  Therefore, if you intentionally over power your shot, but obviously hook your arm to the left - the meter will sway to the left.  (Same concept if you want to hook right).  This works 95% of the time for myself, your results may vary.

Answer (score 2):

The swing is not random. In fact, there is a way to make it always hook right if that's what you want. I do it by holding the wiimote completely in an upright position in my hand and shaking it violently around in a clockwise motion. 
It always goes right hook this way and it helps you in many situations. However, it doesn't go left in you shake it counter-clockwise...

Answer (score 1):

The point of the overhit is to trade accuracy for power.  In my experience, the more power you use, the more the bar wobbles.  So if you barely break past "max" power, it barely wobbles.  But if you really hammer that ball, the wobble gets really big.  And the ball will arc in the direction of the wobble.

To answer your question, I don't know of any way to dictate which way the swing meter will wobble.  Angling the Wiimote will add an arc to the left or right, so you can make a guess which way it will wobble, and angle the wiimote the other way to compensate.  But if you guess wrong, you'll be exacerbating the angle.

If you're going for best score, your best bet is to use *slightly* more power than the swing meter.  This doesn't come with very large accuracy penalties, but get the ball a bit further.  Or, in case you're not using the 1W, switch up to a different club, and use less power.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if you point the sensor of the remote down and then pull or push, so if you want the ball to go left you swing and as you follow through pull the remote towards you, and if you want to go right you push it away. You have to keep the remote pointing down the whole way and don't twist your body when you are pushing or pulling.